# Sitecore 8.2 update 1 Social media connector in Azure Webapp

Tags: sitecore-client, social-connected

I'm working on Social connector functionality to share item content from Sitecore to targeted social networks (facebook, twitter, Google Plus, Linked In).

Based on  reference, my understanding is social media is inbuilt feature in Sitecore latest versions (i.e 8.2 u1)

I’ve created developer apps in social media

- Facebook: generated Application ID, API key, Secret keys
  (authorized)
- Google Plus: generated Application ID, API key, Secret keys
  (authorized)
- LinkedIn: generated Application ID, API key, Secret keys
  (authorized)
- Twitter: generated Application ID, API key, Secret keys (Unable
  to authorize from Sitecore)

Currently, I can able to share posts to facebook as below.

[image]

Challenge1: Unable to capture statistics/analytics i.e likes, comments from facebook (I assume this needs app review/approval from Facebook for respective fields)

Challenge2: Currently, only 3 options were shown to send content messages as default i.e facebook, Twitter, Social media marketer. Need to add configuration to show linkedIn and Google+ also

[image]

Challenge3: Unable to authorize twitter app ( shown below error)

[Whoa there! The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake."]

Any thoughts or references would be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Siva

Comment: Sitecore has provided patch fix to make it work https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4560/sitecore-8-2-1-social-connected-module-content-message-posting-statistics-are