# Sitecore 8.2.1 Social Connected Module - Content Message posting statistics are not working for Facebook

Tags: social-connected

I am using Sitecore 8.2.1. I have followed the steps mentioned in the Social Content posting from [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/social_connected/setting_up_social_connected/configuring/walkthrough_configuring_social_connected_for_posting_messages).

I am able to post the content messages on my FB page. However, likes and comments to that messages are not flowing back to Sitecore when I click "Refresh Statistics".

[image]

I am not using social login. Are there any permissions required in FB app to have these statistics working?

Note: - My FB app is live and in non-dev status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore have registered the behavior as a bug for Sitecore 8.2.1 version.Use public reference number 158997 to track the future status of this bug report.

Please apply the following patch in order to overcome the issue:

1. Place the attached Sitecore.Support.158997.dll assembly to the bin folder of your solution.

I have uploaded this dll on onedrive. Please use this **[link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlklfAV2EyrBprpKonU5qCQwgRe7aQ)** to access the same

2. Open ...App_Config/Includes/Social/Sitecore.Social.Facebook.config file and replace the following row:

`<provider type="Sitecore.Social.Facebook.Networks.Providers.FacebookProvider, Sitecore.Social.Facebook"/>`

with the following one:

`<provider type="Sitecore.Support.Social.Facebook.Networks.Providers.FacebookProvider, Sitecore.Support.158997"/`>